# Lubridate Date parsing is one year off

Tags: r, lubridate

Within R, I'm trying to convert a text string into a Date variable type using lubridate's as.Date function.

I have a vector of values such as:

```
Dates
```

> 11/28/2019
>   11/29/2019

I am attempting to convert these to standard date variables using this as.Date function:

```
as.Date(Dates, "%m/%d/%y")
```

I do not receive an error message, and it correctly interprets the month and date, but for some reason it's outputting the wrong year - one year ahead:

> "2020-11-28"
>   "2020-11-29"

I have no earthly idea why it is incorrectly interpreting the year in this way. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `%Y` for 4 digit year as `%y` refers to only 2 digit

```
as.Date(Dates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

---

Or using `lubridate`, this would be resolved

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(Dates)
```

---

Or with `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(Dates)
```